# Speed formula intuition, dividing distance by time

Tags: speed

I have a vague intuition as to why speed is distance / time, but mathematically speaking I don't understand the division aspect of it.

One of the first things I learned in arithmetic was that you can't add oranges to apples (not unless you abstract them both to "fruit"); that essentially, numbers in an operation need to be of the same unit.

How can you divide say, $x$ kilometers by $y$ hours? Based on my notion of division, it would mean "how many times do $y$ hours fit into $x$ kilometers?", which doesn't make any sense to me.
Of course I understand the idea of $x$ kilometers *per* $y$ hours, but I don't see how *per* turns into division.

How do you make sense out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because we are not simplifying: at least not Ina direct sense. Take $2\dfrac{m}{s}$ this is somewhat like saying $\dfrac{2 oranges}{3 apples}$ It doesn't simplify, but, in the m/s case, it has meaning.

Comment: Are you saying that the division bar in rates isn't to be interpreted as division in the arithmetic sense of the word? We use a division bar but we could've just as well used a wavy line or a dotted one?
My problem originated from assuming that there is a connection between divison and the "per" in rates.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff while they are the same, it helps to think more along the lines of per